# How set 24 hours format in X- axis of react-d3-chart-graphs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

[image]sample Input:

```
const data = [
{
    values: [
        {
            title: 'runTime',
            dateStart: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 20:16:05.000',
            dateEnd: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 21:10:06.000',
        },
        {
            title: 'downTime',
            dateStart: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 21:11:05.000',
            dateEnd: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 21:21:06.000',
        },
        {
            title: 'runTime',
            dateStart: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 21:21:10.000',
            dateEnd: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 22:10:06.000',
        },
        {
            title: 'unScheduled',
            dateStart: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 22:15:00.000',
            dateEnd: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 22:30:00.000',
        },
        {
            title: 'runTime',
            dateStart: 'Mon, 26 Nov 2023 22:31:00.000',
            dateEnd: 'Mon, 27 Nov 2023 00:50:00.000',
        }
    ],
}
```

];

const axesProps = {
legend: {
xAxis: 'Hours',
//yAxis: 'Label left axis',
},
padding: {
xAxis: 2,
yAxis: 2,
},
tickFormat: {
xAxis: timeFormat('%d %B %y %H:%M'),//need a way to display 24 hours on x-axis.
},
};

```
const stackColors = {
'runTime': {
    color: '#41fc03',
    legend: 'RUN TIME',
},
'unScheduled': {
    color: '#0390fc',
    legend: 'UNSCHEDULED/BREAK TIME',
},
'changeOver': {
    color: '#fceb03',
    legend: 'CHANGEOVER',
},
'downTime': {
    color: '#fc0320',
    legend: 'DOWN TIME',
},
```

};

```
export default () => {
const handleBarHover = (item) => {
    console.log('hovered', item);
};

const handleBarClick = (item) => {
    console.log('clicked', item);
};

return (
    <GanttChart
        axesProps={axesProps}
        data={data}
        handleBarHover={handleBarHover}
        handleBarClick={handleBarClick}
        paddingMultiplier={0.6}
        stackColors={stackColors} />
);
```

};

I have used @hh.ru/react-d3-chart-graphs. Please help me to display the hours present in the input along the x-axis.[image: As displayed in picture I could plot the chart but unable to display the hours in x-axis]

Comment: I tried making changes in xAxis: timeFormat('%d %B %y %H:%M'), but it didn't work